# How do I make vim automatically apply c++ syntax highlight on Arduino files (.ino/.pde)?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, arduino

How do I make vim automatically apply c++ syntax highlight on Arduino files (.ino/.pde)?

Or how does vim syntax highlight know what is a c++ file? And how can I tell him that files that is called .ino and .pde is also c++ files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add something like this to `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.ino,*.pde set filetype=cpp
```

Or more correctly, to `~/.vim/ftdetect/cpp.vim`.

Answer (score 4):

Vim searches for syntax files named `{name}.vim` where name represents the language, for example `cpp.vim` for c++ files. If you want that an `.ino` file has his own syntax highlight create a file called `~/.vim/syntax/ino.vim` and you can start use it with `:set syntax=ino`. In your case you can create a link to a `cpp.vim` file.

`ln -s /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/syntax/cpp.vim ~/.vim/syntax/ino.vim`

Answer (score 3):

You can create an autocommand as follows:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pde,*.ino set filetype=c++
```

Put this into your `.vimrc` to make the setting persistent.